# view($id = null) what does it mean?

Tags: cakephp

```
    function view($id = null) {
    $this->Post->id = $id;
```

What is the purpose of ($id = null)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses `null` as the default value for the function argument `$id`. See [Default argument values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) for the details.